# Show a list in page view in TYPO3 backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a custom table that can be edited by users in List view in TYPO3 backend.

For better usability, it would be great to display that table in Page view, so they don't have to change between List view and Page view. This is possible for FE-Users (see screenshot) - so my question is: How can I have this feature for an extension table?

[image: FE Users Entries in Page View]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the table in $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['cms'], for example via your LocalConfiguration or AdditionalConfiguration.php file.

Add a config in that section that looks like:

```
'EXTCONF' => array(
    'cms' => array(
      'db_layout' => array(
         'addTables' => array(
            'fe_users' => array(
               0 => array(
                  'MENU' => '',
                  'fList' => 'username,usergroup,name,email,telephone,address,zip,city',
                  'icon' => TRUE
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Find the documentation for that feature at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Examples/TablesInPageModule/Index.html

Comment: it appears this was deprecated: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/Examples/TablesInPageModule/Index.html (this is for 8.7, newer versions of that page do not exist). The link to the documentation is broken.